# Gulp4 migration - Invalid glob argument

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm working on gulp migration from version 3.9.0 to gulp version 4.0.0.

I'm getting an error in the gulpfile.js on gulp.src('') and the error message is "Error: Invalid glob argument: "

My gulp.task() in gulpfile.js looks like this -

```
gulp.task('build-version', function(done) {
    var dir = path.build + '/js',
        filename = "build.js";

    gulp.src('')
        .pipe(ngConfig('ppm', {
            createModule: false,
            constants: {
                newUIBuildVersion: buildVersion
            }
        }))
        .pipe(rename(filename))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dir));

    // lint build.js file
    return gulp.src(dir + '/' + filename)
        .pipe(jshint(config.jshint))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
        .on('error', function(err) {
            log(err);
        });});
```

and the gulp version : 4.0.0, Node version : 8.11.4

My error message : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVJGU.jpg)

Please find the image of the error message in the terminal.

Does anyone has any idea how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: You have nothing here: : `gulp.src('')`.

Comment: Yeah I know but my previous version of gulpfile.js had empty string only and it was working absolutely fine . Any suggestions what can I pass inside gulp.src('').

Comment: Thanks for responding, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled on this question and found thru research the issue since it seems it doesn't look to be fully answered.

Yes the issue stems from `gulp.src('')` being empty but in Gulp 3 this was ok and allowed by default.

According to the Gulp docs (written for 4.0 as source of truth not from a migration standpoint), it appears that you can pass in a **option** `allowEmpty` which is false by default. So if you have in your code `gulp.src('')` you will need to specify the `allowEmpty` option as well.

An example they provide for the context is `src(globs, [options])`

Here's an example: `gulp.src('', {allowEmpty: true})`

If that doesn't work, other articles I read said : `gulp.src([], {allowEmpty: true})` or : `gulp.src('.', {allowEmpty: true})`

Here's a link for all the options if you run into other issues.

https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src#errors

Hope this helps! Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get it to work with : `gulp.src('.', {allowEmpty: true})` which passes the current directory in

Comment: just incase it helps someone else, - gulp in my case was looking for a specific file which didn't exist, same error.

Comment: a space worked also `gulp.src(' ', {allowEmpty: true})`